# Database-design dilemma

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a question about my current project. It's an online registry system for a certain organization.

I have this problem on how I can determine the attendance of members in a certain 'conference'.

I have a table in my database named 'members' which contains all information about their registration and a 'conference' table too. There are conferences every year and members register to it in able to be a participant in that conference. I need to have a view function for the 'admin' to see who attended the the previous conference.

The idea I have already is that I will add 'first_conference' column in the 'members' table and set a value like '1' if that member registered or attended the 'first_conference' so that if admin chooses to view the attendance in the 1st conference, members with '1' as value of the 'first_conference' column will be showed in the page.

The thing is it is yearly and I'm finding something like a better algo for this. because if I go with my idea, I'll be like adding new column every year to the table 'members' e.g. ('second_conference', 'third_conference', ... , 'nth_conference')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this relation is called `many-to-many` that means for each member there will be multiple conferences and for each conference there will be multiple members.

you should break this relationship by using a third table lets call it `conf_members` and its columns is something like `id, member_id, conference_id, attended` then whenever you have a conference you will create a new row in `conference` table and for example the new conference id is `10` and then you send invitation to members and for each new invitation you add a new row to our new table for example:

```
id, member_id, conference_id, attended
1 , 2        , 10           , 0
1 , 5        , 10           , 0
1 , 4        , 10           , 0
1 , 3        , 10           , 0
```

once the member attend you change the attended from `0` to `1` 
if you are inviting someone who is not yet a member, you should add a record for that one in your `members` table and then add a reference to that member to this table.

so now you don't need to touch your database anymore, and you can easily generate your view by using `join` between your `members` , `conferences`, `conf_member` tables.

Comment: oh i haven't considered that. well, i understand your solution and i think you're suggesting that i use 'foreign key' right? like in the new table you're suggesting, 'conf_members' have columns 'member_id' referenced from 'members' table and 'conference_id' referenced from 'conferences' table. is that how you're suggesting me to do it? thanks. :)

Comment: Ya forgot to mention that `member_id`, `conference_id` should be foreign keys